# Misunderstanding Permutations with Repetition

Tags: combinatorics

The [wikipedia entry on Permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) has this section on Permutations With Repetition:

> Ordered arrangements of the elements of a set S of length n where
>   repetition is allowed are called n-tuples, but have sometimes been
>   referred to as permutations with repetition although they are not
>   permutations in general. They are also called words over the alphabet
>   S in some contexts. If the set S has k elements, the number of
>   n-tuples over S is:
>
> $${\displaystyle k^{n}}$$ There is no restriction on how often an
>   element can appear in an n-tuple

That seems simple enough. But to make sure I understood, I wanted to go through a small example by hand. Consider `S = {a,b}` (so `k=2`) and `n=3`. So the number of ordered permutations should be 2^3 = 8. But it seems to me I can come up with >8:

- a,a,a
- a,a,b
- a,a,c
- a,b,a
- a,b,b
- a,b,c
- a,c,a
- a,c,b
- a,c,c

...That's already 9 and I haven't started on anything starting with `b` or `c` yet. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious in my misinterpretation of this but not sure what it is. Any helpful explanation would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with $S=\{a, b\}$ but then use $c$.

If $S=\{a, b, c\}$, then you should expect $3^3=27$ "permutations with repetition".

(I personally would not call something with repetitions a "permutation", rather a "sample with replacement" or similar.)

Comment: wow what a dumb mistake on my part. Thanks for the quick answer and suggestion on better nomenclature.